# Fashion color matching or fashion matching colors

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis

I am working on an app that gives suggestions on how to match colors for your clothes and I am looking for a tagline for the app.

Which is better? "Fashion color matching" or "Fashion matching colors" or "Matching fashion colors"? Or is there a better choice of words? I am not a native English speaker so I don't know which formulation sounds more natural.

Comment: If you can get away without using the word 'fashion', 'color matching' would be the obvious choice. Stringing nouns (and other descriptors) together doesn't always give a reasonable-sounding or a clearly understood result in English. Though there may be a disproportionate number of Google hits in this style (eg  _new arrival flat casual summer sweet brief fashion color_ ) in tag-happy ads. If you need the general category, "Fashion: color matching" is more acceptable.

Comment: It's a tagline he's after, not a category. _Fashion color matching_ is a good choice, or perhaps _Color matching for fashion_.

Comment: I agree with @Elendil's last suggestion, in part because "color matching" is an ambiguous phrase without context

Comment: What about something like *wardrobe coordination*?

Comment: Or, "color coordination of your wardrobe."

Comment: Wardrobe coordination implies color matching.

Comment: Fashion-wise color--

Answer (score 1):

How about making the tagline sound more active by having the verb in front? ie "Matching colors in style," "Matching colors for fashion"

Answer (score 0):

How about "Matching colors fashionably"?

Or "Fashionable color matching."

Answer (score -1):

You can use below tag lines for your app,

- A style for every story.
- Be your own label.
- Designed for fit. Loved for style.
- Fashion is nothing without people.

Comment: **DON'T** leave a link to your website under your posts. This is considered [spam](/help/promotion).

Comment: Your suggestions provide no connection to the OP's needs of matching colors. Please edit your answer if you can make it more relevant